# Need to begin with a clean slate - How to?

Tags: web2py

Have started playing with pythonanywhere, and am ready to start over. Can I reset back to a virgin clean slate without abandoning my free account and starting over?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to email the support team (support@pythonanywhere.com) and ask for your account to be wiped clean.

See: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/14321/